# Why am I not able to use implicit initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, implicit

This is what I have:

```
Complex.h
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex(double initialRealPart, double initialImaginaryPart = 0.0)
    : realPart(initialRealPart), imaginaryPart(initialImaginaryPart)
    {
    }
    Complex() { }

private:
    double realPart;
    double imaginaryPart;
};


int main()
{
    Complex c = 4.5;
}
```

Isn't implicit initialization supposed to work in this situation?

EDIT:
Oops, I actually had realPart and imaginaryPart as doubles in my code. It's still not working, though.

When I try to initialize implicitly, it says no suitable conversion from double to Complex.

EDIT2:
I also had a Complex() constructor that didn't take in any arguments in my Complex.h

Comment: The code you have posted is well-formed and should compile as-is.  What is your question?

Comment: It compiles fine for me. What compiler are you using? Are you getting a compile error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: It is supposed to work, and it does work. Please, don't ask meaningless questions like "why it doesn't work". Tell us what exactly is wrong in your case. Do you get a compiler error? If you do, then which line produces the error? Or do you observe a run-time problem?

Comment: ...Of course, one obvious irregularity is that you are trying to store a `double` value in an `int` field, which will truncate the value. Was that your intent?

Comment: Any other constructors you're not showing?

Comment: Two possible reasons: Your compiler is bad (and you still haven't said which one), or there's more code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your mistake is that you made `realPart` and `imaginaryPart` to be of type `int`

Otherwise this code has no errors.